# One to Many LINQ query - Assembly does not have definition for SELECT

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am an experienced SQL Developer trying to learn LINQ.  Say I have the following classes:

```
    public partial class Course
        {
            public Course()
            {
                this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
                this.Students1 = new HashSet<Student>();
            }

            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Student> Students1 { get; set; }
        }

public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> age { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> courseid { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to get all the Students on the Computing course i.e. the student objects should be returned as a collection in the Course Object.  I have tried this:

```
from c in Courses
.Include(s => s.Students)
.Where(c => c.name.StartsWith("Computing"))

select new {
c.name,
Students = c.Select(x => x.Students)
```

}

The error I get in LINQPAD is: Cannot execute text selection: 'Lib.Course' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Lib.Course' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Comment: The message is crystal-clear. You are trying to call `Select` on a Course `c.Select(x => `. The Course class doesn't IEnumerable<> so it doesn't have `Select`. A typo perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to write `Students =  c.Students` ?

Comment: BTW the code doesn't compile. You can't use `select new {` like this. This causes confusion and wastes the time of people that try to answer about the malformed code instead the error message. Not good.

Comment: If you have the message `Cannot execute text selection ..` then you must have selected/highlighted a section of code and LinqPad is only trying to compile that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Course is not an IEnumerable so it does not support Select method. As I see, you use LINQ query syntax (not method syntax as other solutions suggests), so you have to use this in your code:

```
from c in Courses
  .Include(s => s.Students)
  .Where(c => c.name.StartsWith("Computing"))

select new {
  c.name,
  c.Students
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write:

```
var res = Courses.Where(x => c.name.StartsWith("Computing"));
```

It will give you all courses (with students) that start with `Computing`

Comment: I believe you should add .ToList() as well?

Comment: If a list is desired than yes.

Comment: The compiler would raise a different error if that was the OP's actual problem. Complaining about `Course.Select` means that the actual code is something like `.Select(c=> new {c.name,Students = c.Select(x => x.Students)}`. I assume the OP didn't copy the code correctly

Answer (score 0):

To be perfectly explicit:

```
var computerCourses = context.Students
   .Where(c => c.name.StartsWith("Computing"));
   .SelectMany(c => 
          c.Students.Select(s => new { CourseName = c.name, Student = s })
   .ToList();
```

This will give you a **flat list** of an anonymous type with fields 'CourseName' and 'Student', which is what I think you are after.

So the main problem with your query was the Select on the Course.Students collection: This collection which contains Student objects, which don't have a member 'Students' themselves - so you can't select that.

I would recommend coding these things in Visual Studio. Like this, your compiler will tell you exactly which statement is not correct, not only the line.

Also, in general I recommend using LINQ-Method-Chain over LINQ-Query syntax ('from' 'select' etc.) .. I find it is easier to think about the objects you're effectively dealing with. And it also helps me to keep apart SQL and LINQ syntax - they are quite similar, but work quite differently.